# Html Tidy with php code, XHTML is not valid XML afterwards

Tags: html, xhtml, tidy, htmltidy

I'm using http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ to convert HTML to XHTML and I want to transform this XHTML later with XSLT.

Unfortunately I tried a to parse a techcrunch site (just for testing). The techcrunch site contains php code and HTML tidy produces a NOT valid XML file with this php code.

Simplified input file `dirty.htm`:

```xml
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.crunchbase.com/company/google" onclick="<?php tc_set_omniture_attr("post_widget_crunchbase") ?>Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and my output file with HTML Tidy `cleaned.htm`:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="http://www.crunchbase.com/company/google" onclick="<?php tc_set_omniture_attr(">Google</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem is the `<` in `onclick` which is not allowed as a XML attribute! XSLTProc refuses to open this not valid XML.

My HTML Tidy Options `tidyconfig.cfg`:

```
output-xhtml: 1
indent: 0
tidy-mark: 0
wrap: 0
alt-text:
doctype: strict
force-output: 1
numeric-entities: 1
clean: 1
bare: 1
word-2000: 1
drop-proprietary-attributes: 1
enclose-text: 1
logical-emphasis: 1
```

HTML Tidy commandline:

```
tidy -quiet -config tidyconfig.cfg -output cleaned.htm dirty.htm
```

Did I missed any HTML Tidy option? All Tidy options: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidy only has [limited support for PHP code](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/). I suspect it is getting confused because the PHP block is inside an attribute (that isn't closed).

It might have a better chance at:

```
<a href="..." onclick="<?php tc_set_omniture_attr("post_widget_crunchbase") ?>">Google</a>
```

Sorry, not sure there's much else that can be done. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to remove onclick from the link, and instead move the onclick script to between some script tags?

Comment: no. no chance of restructuring before HTML Tidy. Because I do not know how the HTML looks like before I use HTML Tidy.